# How to connect to remote SQL server instance by IP

Tags: sql-server

I have a remote development box with SQL 2016 installed.  Remotely, I can access that server by IP just fine.  Let's assume for my question that IP address is 1.1.1.1.

Now I have installed a new SQL 2019 version with an instance name of 'newinstance'.  I am trying to access that remotely with 1.1.1.1\newinstance, but I get a network error stating it can't connect.

Again, I can access the 2016 default instance by IP just fine.  I can't access the 2019 named instance.

- I verified the 2019 instance has remote connections enabled.
- I am able to connect to the 2019 instance just fine when logged in locally to the remote machine.

Can someone give some reasons why this isn't working?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any firewalls enabled (e.g. the default Windows firewall)?

Comment: Good thought, but we use an external firewall, and the Windows versions are turned off.  And both machines are behind the firewall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Named instances are listening on a TCP port randomly assigned at installation. If SQL Browser service is disabled, the client must know the port number. If your sql2019 instance is listening on port 59036, you would connect to 1.1.1.1,59036.

You can find out the port in SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager.(sorry, I don’t have a SQL Server nearby at the moment to give the exact instructions to find it)

If SQL Browser service is active, you may have a firewall issue as suggested by J.D.

Comment: I usually check this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844771/sql-server-configuration-manager-not-found) to remember how to find configuration manager.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:  Thanks to @eric-prévost answer.  It led me on a path, and I found some things that might be useful to others that I am posting here.  In my configuration, the Windows Firewall is turned off so any inbound/outbound rules don't apply.

The key is to figure out the port the named instance is running under.  One suggestion I found was to look at the Sql Server Configuration Manager and it would show the port.  For example, for the default instance running on 2016, I can see the default port of 1433.

[image]

However, when I looked at my named instance, there is no port listed.  So that was confusing.  It has to be listening on a port, but it's not listed.  I tried changing the port to a fixed value, restarted the SQL server, but it still didn't work.

[image]

It turns out you can find the port it's listening on by getting the process ID and using that with netstat to get the port.  Here's what showed up.  I issued netstat commands for both process IDs and saw the port being used is 64420.

[image]

I was then able to connect to my instance remotely using ...

```
10.168.13.37\newinstance,64420
```

NOTE: My servers are assigned multiple IPs, so don't be confused by the discrepancy between the IP addresses.  Both work.  And both are behind a firewall, so don't go poking around on those.  You won't find much!

Comment: The TCP/IP Properties window can be a bit confusing.  By default, SQL Server will listen on same port for all IPs, so you have to scroll down to "IPAll" section to find the port number.